# В случайной матрице, состоящей из нулей и единиц, найти номер строки, в которой произведение чисел минималь

Tags: c#, массивы, циклы, матрицы

Матрицу я уже написал, но никак не могу придумать, как найти саму строку.
Задача в общем звучит так:
Сформулировать случайную матрицу MxN, состоящую из нулей и единиц, причем в каждом столбце число единиц равно номеру столбца.
В матрице найти номер и строку, в которой произведение чисел минимально

Свой код прикрепляю:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
class joks
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /*
             ПЕРВАЯ ЧАСТЬ ЗАДАНИЯ
        */

        // Объявили переменные
        Random ran = new Random();
        int m = ran.Next(5, 10);
        int n = ran.Next(5, 10);
        int[,] matrix = new int[m, n];
        


        // Заполнение матрицы с учетом условия
        for (int y = 0; y < matrix.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < matrix.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                matrix[y, x] = 0;
                if (y < matrix.GetLength(0) && y <= x)
                {
                    for (int h = y; h >= 0; h--)
                    {
                        matrix[h, x] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Выводим двумерный массив
        for (int y = 0; y < matrix.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < matrix.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                Console.Write(matrix[y, x] + "");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Требуется сделать так, чтобы искался номер строки в которой произведение чисел минимально.

Ну я надеюсь на код конечно.

Comment: Произведение горсти нулей на горсть единиц - минимально? дык ноль же... т.е. просто бери любую строку, в которой есть хотя бы один ноль - вот тебе и ответ.

Comment: Так в большинстве строк (а при нумерации столбцов с нуля - во всех) произведение будет нулевым

Comment: Ну я это понимаю, я думал сделать цикл, который просто возьмет первую попавшую строку с нулем